# Python win32com excel worksheets

Tags: python

How to set default to have 3 worksheets while creating a new workbook using win32com

```
import win32com.client

xl=win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch(“Excel.Application”)
wb=xl.Workbooks.Add()
```

By default office 365 adds with 1 worksheet

Comment: Surely a few seconds of thought would have revealed this to you.  `ws1 = wb.Worksheets.Add()` / `ws2 = wb.Worksheets.Add()`.

Comment: I don't know how to make it a default but [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.add) says Add() takes a path to a template; maybe save a `.xslt` template with three worksheets and try `.Add("c:\path\to\saved_template.xslt")` and see what it does?

Comment: Hi Tim, I don’t want to add sheets like that, I’m looking whether we have any property like xl.visible = True, is there anything like xl.worksheets=3? So every time my code has Workbooks.Add() then it can create an excel with 3 sheets as a default?